# É possível criar método @POST com Jersey retornando uma List

Tags: java, lista, post, jersey

Boa tarde!

Estou desenvolvendo um WebService onde preciso que método de consulta receba um objeto como parâmetro de busca e retorna a lista encontrada no banco. Achei vários tutorias de WebService Jersey, porem nada com complexidade que preciso.

```
@POST
    @Path("/Consultar")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + CHARSET_UTF8)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + CHARSET_UTF8)
    public List<RelacaoCorteVO> Consultar(ConsultaDTO dto) {
        List<RelacaoCorteVO> dtos = null;
        try {
            dtos = getRelacaoCorte().consultar(dto.getCampoConsulta(), dto.getValorConsulta(), dto.getLimite(), dto.getPagina(), true, dto.getNivelMontarDados(), dto.getUsuarioLogado());
            return dtos;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return dtos;
        }
    }
```

Comment: boa tarde, tudo bem? qual o retorno do teu método getRelacaoCorte().consultar()? Outra duvida, não seria melhor você passar como paramentro para esse método o Objeto ConsultaDTO dto? Assim te poupa de enviar esse monte de get. ficaria maios ou menos consultar(ConsultaDTO dto, boolean valor). Esse método retorna uma lista mesmo? Pelo que eu me lembro, no próprio retorno, o Jersey já envia essa lista (Um array desse objeto json). Abraço

Comment: Boa tarde! Bem @CaioAugustoPapai

Comment: Então, na verdade dou manutenção no sistema, realmente não foi bem arquitetado, mas infelizmente hoje pra fazer uma mudança dessas, praticamente teria que reescrever o sistema todo, por isso preciso  webservice que aceite um objeto como parâmetro e retorne uma lista, vou ter que fazer isso pra varias classes. O método consultar retorna um List<RelacaoCorteVO>. Até onde debuguei  a lista e preenchida, só return que acontece algo, que a Lista de Json não é criada.

Comment: E qual a saída que você está recebendo?

Comment: Ai que ta, não da erro nenhum, debuguei não cai no Exeption, mas fiz alguns testes, mudei retorno pra Json, e tentei converter a lista no JAVA e retornar Json pronto , porem o Gson não consegue converter por conta que há vários objetos um dentro do outro, porém alguns tem atributos com o mesmo nome, ai da erro na conversão.

Comment: Você deve utilizar `@RequestBody` para passar seu objeto ao serviço, e para retornar anotar seu DTO com `@XmlRootElement`, se o Jersey estiver configurado adequadamente ele irá lidar com o resto. Caso necessário você pode envelopar sua lista de DTOs em um novo objeto de response e tratá-lo de acordo.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado aos que responderam, o método funciona como está, descobri que é o glassfish que é intermitente, ora funciona, ora não. Tenho este problema com pool de conexão JDBC também com ele. Solução migrar de Container.